# How to remove parent taxonomy name from the title generated by wp_title()?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy "Portfolio Categories", and a few these categories say "Cloth", "Shoes", ...

When open some category page, i want the title to be like 'Site Name | Cloth', but with wp_title(), it becomes 'Site Name | Portfolio Categories | Cloth'

How do i remove the "Portfolio Categories" from the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi **@Edward:**

This is not a generic solution but will probably solve your needs.  If you want to get rid of the `'| Portfolio Categories'` from your site's title just hook the `'wp_title'` filter in your theme's `functions.php` file and remove that from the title string.  Copy this code to the bottom of that file and modify as need be:

```
add_filter('wp_title','your_wp_title');
function your_wp_title($title) {
  $title = str_replace('| Portfolio Categories','',$title);
  return $title;
}
```

Comment: @Edward - Yes, sometimes what we need is simple, which is nice. :)

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - I posted a similar question here, looking for the generic solution: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29020/how-to-remove-taxonomy-name-from-wp-title