# How to remove "Taxonomy name:" from wp_title

Tags: custom-taxonomy, filters, title

The wp_title-generated `<title>` in my custom taxonomy archive pages contains the singular taxonomy name with a colon. I can't figure out where this is coming from (or if it's default Wordpress behavior), and I'd like to remove it.  For example, in the archive page for the term 'Vanilla' in a taxonomy called 'Flavors', the `<title>` is

> Flavor: Vanilla | My Site Name

What I would like the title to be is simply

> Vanilla | My site name

The code in header.php is this:

```
<title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?></title>
```

There's only one function in functions.php that's hooked into wp_title, and it looks unrelated to the Taxonomy name. I can't figure out where this is coming from or how to remove it.

How can I remove this?

(The answer in [How to remove parent taxonomy name from the title generated by wp_title()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6716/how-to-remove-parent-taxonomy-name-from-the-title-generated-by-wp-title) is not generalizable to this, and I'm guessing there's a more direct way to do it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `wp_title` filter to control output

```
function mamaduka_remove_tax_name( $title, $sep, $seplocation ) {
    if ( is_tax() ) {
        $term_title = single_term_title( '', false );

        // Determines position of separator
        if ( 'right' == $seplocation ) {
            $title = $term_title . " $sep ";
        } else {
            $title = " $sep " . $term_title;
        }
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'mamaduka_remove_tax_name', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: This causes the page title to show up `VanillaMy Site Name`. It's missing the separator. Using `add_filter( 'wp_title', 'mamaduka_remove_tax_name', 10, 3 );`

Comment: @supertrue edited my code now it should work properly

Comment: In case of archive pages using `single_term_title` might be suffice (it was for me at least :) )

Comment: Unfortunately, this will overwrite the titles for archive pages, too.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use a SEO plugin to take control of all of your titles.  [WordPress SEO](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/) by Yoast is very good.

Or you could add a filter to `wp_title` to change the output.

```
<?php 
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wpse29020_fix_title', 10, 3 );
function wpse29020_fix_title( $title, $sep, $seplocation )
{
    // If this isn't our flavors taxonomy, just return the title
    if( ! is_tax( 'flavors' ) ) return $title;

    // Get the term
    $obj = get_queried_object();

    // Get the terms name
    $name = sanitize_term_field( 'name', $obj->name, $obj->term_id, 'flavors', 'display' );

    // construct the title
    $title = $name . " $sep " . bloginfo( 'name' );
    return $title;
}
```

Comment: This code changes my titles to `My Site NameVanilla | My Site Name`. Do you have any idea why this might be happening? (See also my comment on Mamaduka's answer.)

Comment: Probably something with your theme.  Make sure it's just `<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>`.  Also, you should follow Mamaduka's answer: more concise and a better use of the WP api(s).