# Taxonomy page shows category in title

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, title

I have a custom taxonomy called 'Genres' within that I have various taxonomies: 'Paintings' 'Drawings' etc. I use the code below to create my page titles.

When viewing the taxonomy page for 'Paintings' I get a page title 'Paintings | Genres | BlogName' whereas I wanted to display only: 'Paintings | BlogName', how can I do that?

```
<title><?php
    /* Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed */
    global $page, $paged;

    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );

    // Add the blog name.
    bloginfo( 'name' );

    // Add the blog description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );

    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        echo " | $site_description";    
    ?></title>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `wp_title` filter, see: [other question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29020/how-to-remove-taxonomy-name-from-wp-title)

They are creating a separate function that handles the output.